# Cookies not deleted on logout

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp-classic, single-sign-on

This is the method where I delete all cookies:

```
private void ClearSessionAndCookies()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(ExpirySession);

    foreach (string cookieName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName)
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Https"]) == 1,
            Domain = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Domain,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1D)
        };
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
}
```

It works perfectly on my development computer where all sites in IIS are localhost on different ports. But, in QA environment, each site has a different subdomain (qa.example.com, mz.example.com, cart.example.com), and no cookies get deleted.

I tried leaving out the line where cookie.Domain is set, nothing changed; tried using Cookies.Add and Cookies.Set just in case

Also, I used this piece of code in my classic ASP site (mz.example.com), that also worked perfectly on my computer:

```
For Each cookie in Response.Cookies
    Response.Cookies(cookie).Expires = DateAdd("d",-1,now())
Next
```

In QA it doesn't, but the old code works

```
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", cookie & "=; Expires = Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly; " & "Domain =" & Session("Domain")
```

Am I missing something related to the different subdomains? The domain in all sites is set to ".example.com".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this logout problem for over two weeks, and I've used some hacks to get over it (url parameters, redirection, etc.). It cost me almost 40 hours of debugging, research, and testing.

In the web.config file of the main site there was missing domain information for one cookie that caused all the problems.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="problemCookie" defaultUrl="http://qa.example.com/" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Adding `domain=".example.com"` solved the problem.